# How to get text dropdown toggle Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, dropdown

I have two toggle dropdowns on my page.

```
Field:
    
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 col-xxl-12" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" onclick="DataField();">
        Select the Field
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 col-xxl-12" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item">Code</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item">Office</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item">Type</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item">Name</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item">Usual Name</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item">Birth Date</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item">Address</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item">Number</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item">Complement</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item">Neighborhood</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item">ZIP</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item">City</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item">State</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item">Country</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item">Spouse Name</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item">Father Name</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item">Mother Name</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    
    <br/>
    
    Type of search:
    
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 col-xxl-12" type="button" id="SearchTypeBtn" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        Select the search
      </button>
      <ul id="SearchType" class="dropdown-menu col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 col-xxl-12" aria-labelledby="SearchTypeBtn">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" data-value="Begins with" >Begins with</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" data-value="Equal to" >Equal to</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" data-value="Ends with" >Ends with</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" data-value="Contains" >Contains</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" data-value="Contains the parts" >Contains the parts</a> 
       </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

I need to get the text from the second dropdown that the user selects. I need there to be a reference by dropdown ID so it doesn't get confused with the first dropdown. I've tried several ways to get the text from the option the user clicks but I always get undefined undefined undefined... Any way to get the text the user selects that doesn't give undefined?

I tried

```
 $("#SearchType a").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // cancel the link behaviour
    selText = $(this).text();
    $("#SearchTypeBtn").text(selText);
  });
```

I tried 02:

```
selText = $('#SearchType').children(':selected').text();
```

I tried 03:

```
$("#SearchType").change(function() {
        selText = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
    });
```

I tried 04:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#SearchType a").click(function(){
            selText = $("#SearchTypeBtn").text($(this).text());
        });
    });
```

I tried 05:

```
selText = $("#SearchType :selected").text();
```

I tried 06:

```
 $('#SearchType li a').on('click', function(){
    selText = $('#SearchType').val($(this).text());
    });
```

Comment: Please add your output screenshot.

Comment: Why are using btn instead of select? In your case i think it'll be easier with select.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong type of element. What you need is a select element. What you're currently using is intended for hyperlinks.

From the Bootstrap documentation: Dropdowns are toggleable, contextual overlays for displaying **lists of links**. [Bootstrap Dropdowns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/)

I'd recommend going with a select element: [Bootstrap Selects](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/forms/select/)

html

```
<select id="myselect">
    <option value="1">Mr</option>
    <option value="2">Mrs</option>
    <option value="3">Ms</option>
    <option value="4">Dr</option>
    <option value="5">Prof</option>
</select>
```

Then just use this to grab the selected value w/jQuery.

```
$( "#myselect" ).val()
```